# QT container, with specified order and no repetitions

Tags: qt, containers, qset

I need somthing similar to QSet, but I need the items to be saved on the order I inserted them

is there such thing?

Comment: Not enough information for response: what types of items do you use, how do you want to insert and access them... It can be any of the next containers: [QMap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html), [QHash](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#qhash), [QVector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html), [QList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html), etc... See [Qt Container Classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html)

Comment: @VladimirBershov - the containers you mentioned are either with repetitions or don't save items by the order I inserted them.

Comment: Why not  simply [QVector::append()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#append) or [insert()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#insert)?

Comment: because I don't want duplicates (and I don't want to manually to check if the value exists every time I want to add a new value)

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of anything like that out of the box in neither Qt nor STL. Boost has something like that I think but it is not that hard to do this yourself.

You could do a wrapper around `QHash` like this:

```
template<typename T>
class MySet : QHash<T, int>
{
public:
    using QHash<T, int>::QHash;

    QVector<T> values() //this 'hides' the base QHash::values() of QHash
    {
        QVector<T> vec(count());

        for(auto it = cbegin(); it != end(); ++it)
        {
            vec[it.value()] = it.key();
        }

        return vec;
    }

    void insert(const T &value)
    {
        if(!contains(value))
        {
            insert(value, m_Data.count());
        }
    }
};
```

The usage is quite similar to `QSet`:

```
MySet<QString> set;
set.insert("1");
set.insert("2");
set.insert("3");
qDebug() << set.values();
```

And that prints the values in order. If you need more `complete` support like iterators also iterating in your desired order you would have to reimplement more functionality but the gist of it would be the same. After all `QSet` is internally `QHash` as well. Note that the above does not support removal without modification.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a QList or a QVector could help.

```
QList<QString> stringList;
//By the way, Qt provides QStringList as a typedef for QList<QString>
stringList.append("A");
stringList.append("B");

qDebug() << stringList.at(0); //A
qDebug() << stringList.at(1); //B
```